# How can I convert kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange data to YUV420P?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, yuv

I'm capturing output from iPad camera and then sending it to a server. I'm new to image processing etc. so I'm learning a lot as I go.

The server needs to receive in YUV420P. Right now all I get is the frame in grayscale pretty much. I'm guessing that's the bi-planar vs planar.

How can I convert data from the camera using the kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange data type into YUV420P frames?

Comment: @darryn.ten At first I was using CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress() to get the data from CVImageBuffer. I was using that when I was getting bgra format. I currently just get the 2 planes, I'm not sure where to go from here. I don't know if the the UV data is interleaved or anything.

Comment: Can you update your question?

Comment: What do I need to update? It already states what needs to be said. I found a lot of stuff on just getting the Y channel but in order to have a YUV420P frame, from my understanding, I have to combine both channels into one memory block. I just tried allocing a memory block to save the data but it's either still gray with some faint green and red stripes, or I get a memory error.

Comment: I figured it out. They cbcr was interleaved. Was able to split them into a single buffer

Comment: Hi ron garay. Here i am facing same problem can you tell me please how to figured it out from that problem?